# MVC5 HTML ActionLink Throws CS1502

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've created a very simple view class in my MVC5 solution.  It uses the Entity Framework and calls one of the controller class's actions.  I want to output a list of VIN numbers as hyperlinks on my home page.

The view class syntax is as follows:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Vehicle Inventory";
}
@model IEnumerable<TavernaMVC.Controllers.InventoryController>

<ul>
 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
   <li><a href="@item.Details">@item</a></li>
 }

</ul>
```

The error is as follows:

```
 CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 
 'System.Tuple.Create<object,int>(object, int)' has some invalid arguments
```

How do I rectify my code so that each VIN's details are output in the view class?  Alternatively, how would I simply output all the VIN values as hyperlinks?

Comment: `@model IEnumerable<TavernaMVC.Controllers.InventoryController>` you don't use controllers as models. Build a proper model then use it to display your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should not use your controller as model. What model class are you using? Since you're talking about VIN I will guess it can be called `Car`:

```
public class Car {
    public int VIN { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller you would then like to do something like:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    var cars = db.Cars.ToList();
    return View(cars);
}
```

Then, define your view as:

```
@model IEnumerable<TavernaMVC.Models.Car>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Vehicle Inventory";
}

<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li><a href="@item.Details">@item.VIN</a></li>
    }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view looks correct if the `TavernaMVC.Controllers.InventoryController` class looks somewhat like:

```
public class TavernaMVC.Controllers.InventoryController
{
   //VIN 
   public string VIN{get;set;}
   //Url to Details
   public URL Details{get;set;}
}
```

and you use this

```
<li><a href="@item.Details">@item.VIN</a></li>
```

as the `li` line

Answer (score 0):

Check for renamed Properties in the first line ...

I had this error after renaming a Property and using the AutoRefactoring in the Visual Studio which does not change the Properties in CSHTM files.